# Flutter first start - maximum depth error

Tags: flutter, installation

I'm trying to test Flutter and see if I can learn it but I'm really struggling with the installation.
I've followed the step by step tutorial from the flutter official doc.

Then when I try to start flutter or run flutter doctor or every other command I got this error every time.
[image]

I've tried to delete flutter sdk, redownload zip, git clone sdk, reboot, change the path, create a new project.
But I got this "Page de codes active: 65001" instead of the flutter version in android studio

And when I run a flutter command I get this pub upgrade and then some error on some maximum heap depth limit.

Could someone help me to understand what's the problem here. Because for a new start with a fresh install and just downloading sdk and running a new project with all plugins installed as mentioned in the getting started guide, I've done nothing else that could mess this up in the first place.

Update:
This is what I get when I run flutter doctor -v to have more info
[image]

Comment: What operation system are you using ?

Comment: My operation system is windows 10

Comment: and what flutter channel are you using ?

Comment: I've tried the stable one and the zip from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: It looks like it's about the recursion count limit, but I don't really know how to change or increase them in windows 10.

Comment: sorry guys a linux user here.... I use to install flutter using a single command "sudo snap install flutter" in my terminal which installs everything required for flutter.. try if there is something like that on windows as well

Comment: Yes, thank you tried to use chocolatey but the same problem is occurring.